# Port-Forwarding insecure?

Tags: server, ports, internet, port-forwarding

I was going to do port-forwarding to create a gaming server with an old PC. I the found out that it makes more things visible to the internet. Is port-forwarding a bad choice considering its insecurities? Also, how will I able to protect my internet and computer if I were to port-forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tehcnically, yes..**

Port forwarding allows external internet connections to contact your router, which then will FORWARD the connection to your computer's internal IP address. After the connection reaches your IP address, it will give input to the server you're running on your computer. So the security will be dependent on how secure the game server software is.

**.. But not likely.**

I wouldn't be too concerned. From my experience of hosting game servers and helping manage them for years, you're hardly ever targeted, and when you are it's usually just a DDoS attack. It would be very out of the ordinary for an attacker to have some exploit for your game server.

Comment: Still, you should keep your game server up-to-date, in case a fix is released for a discovered vulnerability.

Comment: Of course. Although, this wouldn't be a plausible solution to someone that is running say.. A modpack for a specific version of the game. You see this happen a lot for Minecraft.

Hopefully for any game servers you're hosting vanilla or slightly modded, you're keeping them up-to-date just for compatibility with the clients.

Answer (score 0):

**Port forwarding** should only make visible the *port* or *ports* you are forwarding to the inside.

With this said, you can **block/firewall those ports** to **only allow**:

- your *work IP or work subnet*
- your friends
- whatever cafe you are working from
- etc

.. for gaming, I will not be to concerned, it really is **as secure** as the **application** you are forwarding the port to is...

example:

if I forward port **6667(IRC)** to a IRC server on one of my *lan*
computers and that **IRC server** **is** **vulnerable**, then you are screwed :)